# Is there a Fibonacci heap based priority queue for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, priority-queue, fibonacci-heap

Is there a Fibonacci heap/priority queue available for Haskell? (Or even an asymptotically better one?) I found a list of various priority queue implementations in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6976559/1333025), but I couldn't find if any of them satisfies the amortized running time of Fibonacci heaps:

- Find-minimum is *O(1)* amortized time.
- Operations insert, decrease key, and merge (union) work are *O(1)* amortized time.
- Operations delete and delete minimum are *O(log n)* amortized time.

See [the comparison of theoretic bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants).

Comment: It's possible that no production code exists, as the constant factors generally make Fibonacci heaps slower than binomial heaps for reasonable-sized datasets, despite the theoretical asymptotic advantage.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Interesting, could you give a rough estimate for what sizes Fibonacci heaps become advantageous?

Comment: TBH, this is somewhat out of my area; I've only read about such disadvantages (see e.g. [CLRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLRS)).  Don't quote me on it ;)

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pqueue is fairly optimized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a Fibonacci Heap, but just as good: [heaps](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/heaps-0.2.3) by Edward Kmett based on the Brodal/Okasaki persistent variant of Brodal heaps.

Comment: Is there actually anything that E.Kmett hasn't implemented?